# how to test file size in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to Rspec. I'd like to test file size by the image that is over 10Mb in fixtures directory.

user_spec.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/test/matchers'
...

it "is invalid avatar size" do
  image_path = File.join(Rails.root, "spec/fixtures/sample.jpg")
  user = FactoryBot.build(:user, avatar: File.open(image_path))
  user.valid?
  expect(user.errors[:avatar]).to include("should be less than 5MB")
end
```

factories/users.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Donald Fagen"
    username "donald"
    email "donald-fagen@gmail.com"
    password "Thenightfly"
    avatar { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/sample.jpg'), 'image/jpg') }
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
validate :avatar_size
...

private

  def avatar_size
    if avatar.size > 5.megabytes
      errors.add(:avatar, "should be less than 5MB")
    end
  end
```

But it returns

```
1) User validations test invalid information is invalid avatar size
     Failure/Error: expect(user.errors[:avatar]).to include("should be less than 5MB")
       expected [] to include "should be less than 5MB"
```

It looks like avatar_size method doesn't work. Should I save after building user object to go to avatar_size? Please tell me how to check the file size.

- rails: 5.1.6
- rspec-rails: 3.8.1
- factory_bot_rails: 4.11.1

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the sample data. It is 10MB around, but I'm using resize_to_fit: [300, 300], so it's compressed. I've checked by 'binding.pry', and it was less than 5MB.

```
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::ValidationsTest::InvalidInformation>)> @user.avatar.size
=> 43866
```